# Value Picker get error TypeError: resp is null in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I can't figure out where this is going wrong, I have almost the exact same code working on another page. I have the valuePicker getting its values from a viewScope.vsFieldNames and I know that it is populated before I click the value picker, but when the picker dialog displays I get the error

> TypeError: resp is null

the field reqOnSave is a multiline edit box and it is null but I don't think that should make any difference. I have used a scope variable as the valueList in several other pages without trouble. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Edited Oct 17
My page looks like this:

[image: Page Layout]

When I click on Select Fields I get the display below. I know that viewScope.vsFieldNames is properly populated at this point because I examine it using the debug Tool Bar.

I really don't like the xe:valuePicker because it calls a dialog and I would prefer something like a multi-select combobox, but there is not a standard core or Extension Library control that does this (at least that I can find).

[image: Error Message]

Here is my complete code:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <xp:label value="Application" id="label1"
                for="ApplicationCombo">
            </xp:label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <xp:comboBox id="ApplicationCombo"
                value="#{formDoc.Application}">
                <xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var rtn:Array = database.getView("vwWFSApplicationsEnabled").getColumnValues(0);
rtn.unshift("");}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:selectItems>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelBody">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <![CDATA[#{javascript:try{formDoc.replaceItemValue("FormName","");
}catch(e){

}}]]>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:comboBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <xp:panel id="panelBody">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
    var app:string = formDoc.getValue("Application");
    var debug:Boolean = true;
    if (debug) WFSUtils.sysOut("Application = " + app);
    var form:String = formDoc.getValue("FormName");
    if (debug) WFSUtils.sysOut("Form = " + form);
    if (!(app == null || app == "")){
        if ((!(form.substring(0,3) == "---")) && (!(form == null || form == ""))) {
            if (debug) WFSUtils.sysOut("Form Name = " + form);
            var thisForm:NotesForm = appProps[app].appDB.getForm(form);
            if (debug) WFSUtils.sysOut("Got Form Name = " + thisForm.getName());
            var rtn:Array = thisForm.getFields();
            if (debug) WFSUtils.sysOut("Rtn = " + rtn.toString());
            viewScope.vsFieldNames = rtn;
            return null
        }
    }
    viewScope.vsFieldNames = null;
    return null
}catch(e){

    WFSUtils.sysOut("Error in Get Fields " + e.toString());
    viewScope.vsFieldNames = null;
    return null;
}}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <xp:label value="Form Name :" id="label2"
                    for="FormCombo">
                </xp:label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1"
                    value="#{formDoc.FormName}">
                    <xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:this.value>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:var app:string = formDoc.getValue("Application");
if (!(app == null || app == "")){
    var rtn = appProps[app].appDB.getView("vwWFSForms").getColumnValues(0);
    rtn = sort_unique(rtn);
    rtn.unshift("--- Select A Form ---");
    return rtn
}else{
    return null
}}]]>
                        </xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelBody">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:comboBox>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row Form -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <xp:label value="Required Fields On Save :" id="label3"
                    for="djComboReqOnSave">
                </xp:label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <xe:valuePicker id="pickerFields"
                    dialogTitle="Select One or More Fields" for="reqOnSave"
                    pickerText="Select Field/s :">
                    <xe:this.dataProvider>
                        <xe:simpleValuePicker caseInsensitive="false">
                            <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[${javascript:viewScope.vsFieldNames;
}]]></xe:this.valueList>
                        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
                    </xe:this.dataProvider>
                </xe:valuePicker>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <xp:inputTextarea id="reqOnSave"
                    value="#{formDoc.ReqOnSave}" multipleSeparator=",">
                </xp:inputTextarea>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row reqOnSave -->
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </xp:panel>
```

Comment: What control is "resp"?

Comment: Looks as if there was something inside the container called "panelBody" that is trying to do something with a control or an object called "resp" as soon as "panelBody" is updated. You say this is working within a different page; that will be the key: what are the differences?

Comment: Something else I just realized: the screenshot shows something looking like an alert (XPiNC?), but its title "TestError" is somewhat special, doesn't look like a standard system alert, and your code is referring to an object "WFSUtils"; maybe you need to look in there for that mysterious "resp" object...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but something to be noted I feel. I always got "resp is null" with value picker when I lost the session ( as in when the session expired).

Comment: Paul's answer below fixed the problem. Lothar WFSUtils.sysOut simply formates a message then prints it to the server console. and "TestError" is the name of the XPage being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resp is the Client-Side JavaScript variable passed to the picker, so the picker doesn't have any options loaded to it.

The ValuePicker uses `${javascript:viewScope.vsFieldNames;}`. So the fact that it's visible using debug toolbar may be misleading, because the debug toolbar is showing the output *after* the values have been loaded to the ValuePicker.

To use that code, you'll need to be setting `viewScope.vsFieldNames` in `beforePageLoad` event. To double-check it's not null when the code is running, amend to debug out the content before calling `viewScope.vsFieldNames`, e.g. `${javascript:print(viewScope.vsFieldNames); return viewScope.vsFieldNames;}`. The chances are that when it's running the value is not initialised yet.

If you can't set it in beforePageLoad, to solve the problem, instead of `${javascript:viewScope.vsFieldNames;}` (SSJS page load) use `#{viewScope.vsFieldNames}` (EL dynamic). That should work, you'll be avoiding the SSJS parser, so performance will not be negatively impacted.

Comment: The values in vsFieldNames depend on the Application and Form so it can't be in the beforePageLoad so will give a try with the EL.